# Safety of purchasing country-specific domains from registrars?

Tags: domains, domain-registration

None of the previous questions tackle some of the one-off (or further) countries' registries, beyond .co.uk, .it, et al. or else I'd have found an answer myself.

Is it safe to buy a domain from a foreign country TLD from a registrar?

http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/

I'm just looking for information for a vanity domain, so obviously I'm alright without an answer, but it's an unasked question (or at least, unanswered), and I'm not exactly in a hurry to give my credit card information over country lines, sight unseen.

Comment: Also, feel free to mark this CommunityWiki as applicable, I don't have the rep to do so.

Comment: I generalized your question a bit so it's not too localized

Comment: @Jeff perfect - I had contemplated doing the same, but erred on the side of specificity.

Answer (score 1):

Your original question (RE: .gr domains) poses an interesting point - while I can't vouch for any Greek registrars, I have worked with the Spanish registrar Nominalia for years without issue and they do offer .gr registrations at present. (I'm not with them anymore as they hiked their prices eventually and the dollar to euro conversion rate isn't as favorable as it used to be - still, it was fun practicing my Spanish on the e-mails they'd send)

Note that you should only use a bona fide credit card (versus a debit card) when you're shopping online - regardless of where you're spending - because your liability for fraud is significantly reduced. (See [Debit Card: Consumer Protection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debit_card#Consumer_protection) Wikipedia entry for basic explanation)

It's far easier to report fraud on a credit card than haggle with your bank about fraudulent charges after money has been debited from your account - *caveat emptor* and all that.

Comment: Debt protection is a huge, huge point, but informs a part of the question that wasn't as central to the question pre-edit. My main concern was that the US- and larger Eurozone-specific registrars like GoDaddy are rated in other threads by feature list, and was hoping to branch out the same question into non-mainstream TLDs.

Answer (score 1):

Every country has specific rules. Be sure you comply with the rules. Broadly speaking, their are two categories:

1) For some countries, any individual can register the domain. He/she need not be located in the country.

2) For some countries, either the individual must be a resident, or have an office in the country.

Lookup on wikipedia for the specific extension you are interested in.

The care you need to take is: Some registrars will take care and refuse the registration if the address you specify does not satisfy the criteria. Others might just go ahead and register the domain, and you may face disqualification later.